# Get properties of a pdf file by using PHP

Tags: php, pdf

I have on pdf document. I want to print the details of pdf like page size by using php.

I have this code

```
<?php 

  $pdffile = "C:\Users\suresh\Downloads\Invoice_52683.pdf";
  $pdfinfo = shell_exec("pdfinfo ".$pdffile); 

  // find height and width
  preg_match('/Page size:\s+([0-9]{0,5}\.?[0-9]{0,3}) x ([0-9]{0,5}\.?[0-9]{0,3})/',      $pdfinfo,$heightandwidth); 
  echo $width = $heightandwidth[1]; 
  echo $height = $heightandwidth[2]; 

 ?>
```

This is my code can any one help regarding this.

Thanks in advance

Comment: For the size of a file you just need `filesize()`, if there's any problem show us the error

Comment: Hello, am not looking for file size am looking for dimensions of a pdf file. Ex: 8.5 x 11 this is the page size... want to display these values from php

Comment: So... have you tried the code? what are the errors? post the errors or the problem you've noticed

Comment: Hello, Notice: Undefined offset: 1 in      D:\xampp\htdocs\test\page_size.php on line 8

Notice: Undefined offset: 2 in D:\xampp\htdocs\test\page_size.php on line 9                  These are the errors

Comment: Which is your pdfinfo.exe's path?

Comment: Don't know ... I found this code in online try to execute this found these errors..... can u help me in this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First check your `pdfinfo`'s path, if you don't have it: [XPDF](http://www.foolabs.com/xpdf/download.html)... so then change your code:

```
$pdffile = "C:\\Users\\suresh\\Downloads\\Invoice_52683.pdf";
$pdfinfo_path = "C:\\path\\to\\pdfinfo.exe";
$pdfinfo = shell_exec($pdfinfo_path." ".$pdffile);

// find height and width
preg_match('/Page size:\s+([0-9]{0,5}\.?[0-9]{0,3}) x ([0-9]{0,5}\.?[0-9]{0,3})/',$pdfinfo,$heightandwidth); 
echo $width = $heightandwidth[1]; 
echo $height = $heightandwidth[2];
```

If you use Linux: `$pdfinfo_path = "/path/to/pdfinfo";`

Comment: Thanks for help if any queries i will ping

Answer (score 1):

```
function get_xmp_array( &$xmp_raw ) {
    $xmp_arr = array();
    foreach ( array(
        'Creation Date'     => '<xmp:CreateDate>(.*?)<\/xmp:CreateDate>',
        'Modification Date' => '<xmp:ModifyDate>(.*?)<\/xmp:ModifyDate>',
        'Title'             => '<dc:title>\s*<rdf:Alt>\s*(.*?)\s*<\/rdf:Alt>\s*<\/dc:title>',
        'Subject'           => '<dc:description>\s*<rdf:Alt>\s*(.*?)\s*<\/rdf:Alt>\s*<\/dc:description>',
        'Creator'           => '<dc:creator>\s*<rdf:Bag>\s*(.*?)\s*<\/rdf:Bag>\s*<\/dc:creator>',
        'Keywords'          => '<dc:subject>\s*<rdf:Bag>\s*(.*?)\s*<\/rdf:Bag>\s*<\/dc:subject>') as $key => $regex ) {
    // get a single text string
    $xmp_arr[$key] = preg_match( "/$regex/is", $xmp_raw, $match ) ? $match[1] : '';

    // if string contains a list, then re-assign the variable as an array with the list elements
    $xmp_arr[$key] = preg_match_all( "/<rdf:li[^>]*>([^>]*)<\/rdf:li>/is", $xmp_arr[$key], $match ) ? $match[1] : $xmp_arr[$key];

    // hierarchical keywords need to be split into a third dimension
    if ( ! empty( $xmp_arr[$key] ) && $key == 'Hierarchical Keywords' ) {
        foreach ( $xmp_arr[$key] as $li => $val ) $xmp_arr[$key][$li] = explode( '|', $val );
            unset ( $li, $val );
        }
    }
    return $xmp_arr;
}

$file = "path to pdf file";
$f = fopen($file,'rb');
if(!$f)
    return false;

//Read the last 16KB
fseek($f, -16384, SEEK_END);
$s = fread($f, 16384);
print_r(get_xmp_array($s));
```